# Server image right after the domain name in Django and Heroku

Tags: django, url, heroku, static, django-staticfiles

Is there a way to achieve this in Django hosted on Heroku?

```
http://www.exampledomain.com/imageofacar.jpg
```

Image to be server right after the domain name? I am not looking for a solution via nginx server or static server, my domain is running on django.

Comment: You want to serve this static image with Django? You are using the Django development server to serve your domain?

Comment: Yes server static image with Django, but not /static/ but exactly like this: http://www.exampledomain.com/imageofacar.jpg - right after the /